# Trying to Create a "dynamic" Function inside a Loop

Tags: function, loops, python-3.7

I'm new to Python and trying to test myself with general code that features things I know or causes me to go searching for answers and solutions as to why what I'm trying to do doesn't work. Unfortunately, I've hit a dead-end in my current attempt.

I got lasered in on the concept of creating a small authorization program inside a single script, and while trying to limit the number of failed log-in attempts the user was allotted, I ran into an issue with the following code:

```
def attempts(n):
a = n - 1
while a > 0:
    result = a
    return result
Username = input('Please enter a New Username: ')
Password = input('Please enter a New Password: ')
logu = Username
logp = Password
LoginU = input('Please enter your Username: ')
if LoginU != logu:
    while LoginU != logu:
    LoginRetry = input('Please try again')
    att = attempts(3)
    att
    print(att)
else:
print('Welcome to the Environment!')
pass
print('Exiting Environment. Have a good day.')
```

Good practice and ugly code aside, my chief issue lies in getting the (n) to reduce inside the loop with each iterative attempt. As of right now, when I execute the script and intentionally enter the wrong username, it loops

> ```
> Please try again:
> 2
> Please try again:
> 2
> ```

until I enter the correct username. Under proper operation, I'd like it to spit

> ```
> Please try again:
> 2
> Please try again:
> 1
> Please try again:
> Exiting Environment. Have a good day.
> ```

I'd appreciate any and all solutions, or advice people can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach you can take.  A few notes:

1. Instead of subtracting from a counter, loop over an iterable to count.  `for` loops are genrally easier to think about than `while` loops.  Whenever you want to do something a certain number of times, use a `for` loop.  You can always `break` out of them if you need to.
2. The best way to approach breaking your code into functions is to try to make all of the "actions" of your program into their own functions.

---

```
import sys

def login(username, password):
    username_input = input('Please enter your Username: ')
    password_input = input('Please enter your Password: ')
    return username == username_input and password == password_input

def login_n_tries(n, username, password):
    for i in reversed(range(n)):
        if login(username, password):
            return True
        print(f"You have {i} attempts remaining")
    return False

username = input('Please enter a New Username: ')
password = input('Please enter a New Password: ')
if not login_n_tries(3, username, password):
    print("Login failed")
    sys.exit(1)  # End program
... # Rest of program
```